# jquery ui icon not working on inline span

Tags: jquery-ui

As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/kralco626/3BYDu/

The icon does not show up when you use `display:inline`

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>
            <div style="float:left">My Header</div>
            <div style="float:left" class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n"></div>
        </th>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Edit for formatting.

Answer (score 11):

Use`ui-icon`, before of the `ui-icon-ICON` and use the CSS `display:inline-block` should work properly

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home" style="display: inline-block"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, I guess you could try inline-block instead of inline.

Comment: it shows, but under the text. I think the `ui-icon` class gives it `inline-block`

Comment: Ah, browser wars. In my Firefox, inline-block renders the icon next to the text. In my Internet Explorer, it doesn't. Best go with Vinnyq12's answer

Comment: lol, ya and I was testing with chrome :) can't we all just agree on one browser?

Comment: IE7 doesn't do inline-block, and IE8 will only do inline-block if using a proper doctype.  You can fake it by googling up the styling for goog-inline-block, but it's easiest to just float.